# How to avoid silent SMS attack?

Tags: privacy, android, ios, sms

I am worried about silent SMS being used incorrectly by people. What are the ways on which it can be avoided on Android and iOS?

Comment: Can you please explain your concerns better?

Answer (score 2):

Not at all.

Silent SMS is a buzzword that keeps on popping up every couple of years.

Point is that handling control messages that aren't signaled to the user is absolutely basic behavior of any 2G user terminal.

The abuse potential stems from the fact that these leave a trace in your carrier's log files, which then can be queried by e.g. law enforcement.

Anyone with access to these logs doesn't actually *need* a silent SMS to figure out where you're logged in. I think the focus on these comes from a time where law enforcement access wasn't as mature as it is now and people needed "help" finding things in logs.

So, you're worrying about

- something you can't disable, since it makes your phone work
- something that's not the actual privacy problem
- something you haven't researched overly well